# count continous segements that are connected

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

I have found a question on hackerrank .  https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/coders-assemble/challenges/travel-in-treeland .

The question is: you are given a tree. find a connected component where each element x in component satisfies a condition i.e. L<=x<=R, where L and R are some numbers.

The task is to find count all such connected components.

I have tried its brute force approach. I took all the possible ranges of L to R, and checked if it is true. I am getting a time limit exceeded.

p.s. its over a month I have been trying to solve this previous contest's problem, but couldn't find any optimised solution.

for any explanation please comment , will clear as soon as possible.

Edit: i managed to get testcases, can someone explain the answers:

test case 2:  (Expected o/p : 20)

```
10
1 3
1 6
1 2
3 4
6 8
2 7
2 5
4 9
4 10
```

Test case 4: (expected o/p : 17)

```
13
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 4
1 5
3 8
4 6
4 7
8 10
8 9
8 11
8 12
```

Test case 3: (exoected o/p: 8)

```
8
0 2
0 1
0 4
2 3
4 5
5 6
5 7
```

Test case 5: (expected o/p  13)

```
9
0 1
0 5
1 2
1 3
3 4
5 6
5 7
7 8
```

Comment: @Photon, thanks  for the help, but they are different.

Comment: yes it is, [1], [2], [3], [2,3] [1,3] they all are.

Comment: i got the test cases, can't understand how did this answer came. I expected totally different answers, it would be nice, if someone finds explanation for these two.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to draw the tree for test case 2 from above.

```
                    1
        /           |           \
        2           3           6
    /       \       |           |
    5       7       4           8
                /       \
                9       10
```

Obviously there will be **10** connected segments: [1,1] [2,2] ... [10,10]

Now considering segments with length>1:

- **9**: [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [1,5] [1,6] [1,7] [1,8] [1,9] [1,10]
- **1**: [3,4]

Hence total segments=20. These segments are simply derived from *definitions* in the question. I would suggest reading the question again carefully. In case you there is a particular pair that you think should or should not be present, let me know. In this way we can address specific issue/s rather than me explaining the whole question again.

For test case 4, I am slightly unsure as the question states `1 <= ai, bi <=n` but we have 0 as input. Nevertheless the graph looks like:

```
                        0
            /           |           \
            1           2           3
        /       \                   |
        4       5                   8
    /   |                   /   /   |   \
    6   7                   9   10  11  12
```

So the segments would be:

- **13**:[0,0] [1,1] ... [12,12]
- **4**: [8,9] [8,10] [8,11] [8,12]

Comment: i have added two more test cases, there are many more which are in consistent.Thanks for this answer.

Comment: i thought this way but: TEST CASE 3: (expected o/p = 8) 8 (0 2) (0 1) (0 4) (2 3) (4 5 ) (5 6 ) (5 7) –here 8 edges + [2-3], [4 ,5],[4,6] ,[4,7],[5,6],[5,7] i.e. 14 must be answer

Comment: I see your point and have given it a lot of thought but am not able to come up with a valid approach satisfying all four test cases. I believe something incorrect/missing in the question - mostly because of test case 3 (8 elements with 8 expected output). If there is way to raise a concern on hackerrank, I would request you to do it. Also please share your findings here.

Comment: you are correct, there is something missing in this question, there is no possible explanation for these test cases. I tried to find problem setter/ editorial, but there is nothing.